# comma or semicolon before "that is" and repeating 'that'

Tags: semicolons

In the following two sentences

1. We need to show that Phrase; that is, that Phrase A'.
2. We need to show that Phrase A, that is, Phrase A'.

Which one is correct or more natural?

Phrase A and Phrase A' are two sentences that express the same thing. That they are the same are obvious to see and is not our concern. Add an example for sentence 1. (We are not going to show that "a+b=c is the same as a=c-b", which is trivial.)

> We need to show that a+b=c; that is, that a=c-b.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new example now contains a main verb (=, that is, equals), so what you have is correct.

But you can use either a semicolon or commas.

To use a "simpler" sentence:

> 1 We need to show that 2 plus 2 equals 4; that is, that 4 is the sum of
>   2 and 2.

or

> 2 We need to show that 2 plus 2, that is, the sum of 2 and 2, is [equals] 4.

Note the placement of the punctuation and of "that is".

In 1, we have two separate clauses, which we can join with a semicolon; the latter clause is clarifying, and can be removed without making the sentence ungrammatical.

In 2, we have a parenthetical statement. This is also clarifying and can also be removed without affecting the grammaticality or meaning.

A parenthetical statement can also use dashes or parentheses:

> 2a We need to show that 2 plus 2 – that is, the sum of 2 and 2 – is 4.

or

> 2b We need to show that 2 plus 2 (that is, the sum of 2 and 2) is 4.

Note that I have used en dashes in 2a; unspaced em dashes are generally preferred in American English.

Comment: 2 ends up rather heavily comma-laden to me. I’d prefer to set off the parenthetical statement with dashes instead.

Comment: As the OP was asking about commas vs semicolons, I just kept it at that. But of course you're right. I will edit to mention that.

Comment: Do we always need a semicolon or period when joining two independent clauses with "that is", or is a comma enough, too, sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

Of the below answer, the following section (example 1) is **incorrect**:

> Your new example now contains a main verb (=, that is, equals), so what you have is correct.
>
> But you can use either a semicolon or commas.
>
> To use a "simpler" sentence:
>
> 1 *We need to show that 2 plus 2 equals 4; that is, that 4 is the sum of 2 and 2.
>
> In 1, we have two separate clauses, which we can join with a semicolon; the latter clause is clarifying, and can be removed without making the sentence ungrammatical.

This is not true. **A semicolon can only join two independent clauses** (meaning they could stand alone as two separate sentences). In the above example, the first clause is independent, but the second clause is dependent. Notice that the following sentence cannot stand alone:

**That 4 is the sum of 2 and 2.*

**The following modified sentence is now correct,** by removing the *that* and creating two independent clauses joined by a semicolon:

*4 is the sum of 2 and 2.*

So here is our corrected sentence using *that is*, with the two independent clauses in bold:

1 **We need to show that 2 plus 2 equals 4**; that is, **4 is the sum of 2 and 2.**

The remainder of the answer is correct (example 2):

> 2 We need to show that 2 plus 2, that is, the sum of 2 and 2, is [equals] 4.
>
> Note the placement of the punctuation and of "that is".
> In 2, we have a parenthetical statement. This is also clarifying and can also be removed without affecting the grammaticality or meaning.
>
> A parenthetical statement can also use dashes or parentheses:
> 2a We need to show that 2 plus 2 – that is, the sum of 2 and 2 – is 4.
>
> or
>
> 2b We need to show that 2 plus 2 (that is, the sum of 2 and 2) is 4.
>
> Note that I have used en dashes in 2a; unspaced em dashes are generally preferred in American English.

See [Margie Holds Court](https://www.margieholdscourt.com/that-is-and-others/) for a complete explanation of the difference between commas and semicolons in instances like these.